# Followup question, does $\|u\|_{L^\infty(0, 1)} \le \epsilon\|u'\|_{L^p(0, 1)} + C\|u\|_{L^1(0, 1)}$ still hold when $p = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

This is a followup to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658859/exists-c-c-epsilon-p-where-u-l-infty0-1-le-epsilon-u-l).

> Let $p > 1$. For all $\epsilon > 0$, does there exist $C = C(\epsilon, p)$ such that$$\|u\|_{L^\infty(0, 1)} \le \epsilon\|u'\|_{L^p(0, 1)} + C\|u\|_{L^1(0, 1)}\tag*{$(1)$}$$for all $u \in W^{1, p}(0, 1)$?

Does $(1)$ still hold when $p = 1$?

Comment: Note that the *compactness proof* in the [previous post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1659091/70305) fails for $p=1$ because $W^{1,1}(0,1)\subset L^\infty(0,1)$ is not compact. However, $W^{1,1}(0,1)\subset L^q(0,1)$ is compact for all $q\in[1,\infty)$. Thus, for $q\in[1,\infty)$, the following version is true:
$$\|u\|_{L^q(0, 1)} \le \epsilon\|u'\|_{L^1(0, 1)} + C\|u\|_{L^1(0, 1)},\qquad\forall \ u\in W^{1,1}(0,1).$$
In other words: $(1)$ holds for $p=1$ if we replace $L^\infty$ by $L^q$ with $q\in[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $u_n = \max \{ 1-nx, 0\}$. Then $\|u_n\|_\infty = 1$, $\|u'_n\|_{L^1} =1$ and $\|u_n\|_{L^1} \to 0$. Thus if

$$\|u\|_{L^\infty} \le \epsilon\|u'\|_{L^1} + C\|u\|_{L^1}$$

holds for some $C$, take $u = u_n$ and takes $n\to \infty$ gives $1\le \epsilon$, which is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Other counterexample: $u_n(x)=x^n$.

As in the @JohnMa 's answer, $\|u_n\|_{L^\infty}=\|u_n'\|_{L^1}=1$ and $\|u_n\|_{L^1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\to0$.