# Inequalities involving Sobolev spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $I = (0, 1)$. I have two questions.

1. Let $p > 1$. For all $\epsilon > 0$, does there necessarily exist $C = C(\epsilon, m, p)$ such that$$\sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} \|D^j u\|_{L^\infty(I)} \le \epsilon\|D^m u\|_{L^p(I)} + C\|u\|_{L^1(I)} \text{ for all }u \in W^{m, p}(I)?$$
2. Let $1 \le q < \infty$. Do we necessarily have that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $C = (\epsilon, q)$ such that$$\|D^{(m-1)}u\|_{L^q(I)} + \sum_{j = 0}^{m-2} \|D^j u\|_{L^\infty(I)} \le \epsilon\|D^m u\|_{L^1(I)} + C\|u\|_{L^1(I)} \text{ for all }u \in W^{m, 1}(I)?$$

Comment: The answer to 2 is also yes. This whole question is exercise 8.6 in Brezis _Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces, and Partial Differential Equations_. I am writing up solutions to this book, so sometime in the near future I will post an entire answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is yes.

*Proof:* Take $\varepsilon>0$. Let $c>0$ be a constant such that $\|\cdot\|_{L^p}\leq c\|\cdot\|_{L^\infty}$. Set $\eta=\frac{\varepsilon}{1+c\varepsilon}$.

Since [$W^{m,p}(I)\subset C^{m-1}(\overline{I})$ is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660195/do-we-necessarily-have-that-w2-pi-subset-c1-overlinei-with-compact/1665015#1665015) and $C^{m-1}(\overline{I})\subset L^1(I)$ is continuous, the lemma in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1659091/70305) implies that there exists a constant $C_\eta>0$ such that
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\|D^ju\|_{L^\infty}&=\|u\|_{C^{m-1}}\\
&\leq\eta\|u\|_{W^{m,p}}+C_\eta\|u\|_{L^1}\\\\
&=\eta \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\|D^ju\|_{L^p}+\eta\|D^mu\|_{L^p}+C_\eta\|u\|_{L^1}\\\\
&\leq c\eta \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\|D^ju\|_{L^\infty}+\eta\|D^mu\|_{L^p}+C_\eta\|u\|_{L^1}
\end{align}
and thus
$$(1-c\eta)\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\|D^ju\|_{L^\infty}\leq\eta\|D^mu\|_{L^p}+C_\eta\|u\|_{L^1}$$
Taking $C=\frac{C_\eta}{1-c\eta}$, we get
$$\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\|D^ju\|_{L^\infty}\leq\frac{\eta}{1-c\eta}\|D^mu\|_{L^p}+\frac{C_\eta}{1-c\eta}\|u\|_{L^1}=\epsilon \|D^mu\|_{L^p}+C\|u\|_{L^1}$$
as desired.